# when CSV has more column headers than a database table during import

Tags: c#, sql-server, gridview, drop-down-menu

I am trying to import csv to mssql using c# code on a asp.net application.
the below c# code helps to load the csv file, choose the table to import to 
and then a button click event matches columns and populates a gridview (dgvmatchdata)
the gridview has two columns where the left side column lists all the available table headers from db
and right side column lists all the csv headers in a drop down list.

now, there are 3 conditions
1. both table and csv has equal no. of column headers.
2. table has more columns than csv 
3. csv has more columns than table.

i have successfully finished the first two scenarios. and now, i am stuck at the 3rd scenario

my approach to this is, 
for example lets consider the table as 10 columns and csv has 15 columns.
i wish to create 15 rows in dgvmatchdata and display the 10 table column headers on the left side
on their own labels for each. the equivalent righ side of the dgvmatchdata will have a drop down list
which contains 'ignore this column' + 15 columns headers from the csv. so, the ddl will now have 16 items.

i want to place text box for the remaining 5 rows on the table column side and i want to populate 
the text box with dropdown list. selected items.text during dropdown selected item change event.
now after i have successfully got text inside the remaining 5 text boxes i will write a code on a button click event
to alter table in the db and then the next step would simply import the csv data to the altered table flawlessly.

the point where i am seeking help is, i have placed the text box correctly but the text box disappears on ddl.selecteditem changed
due to post back issue and i am unable to get the text inside the text box.

kindly help.

**Gridview Code**

```
   protected void dgvmatchdata_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["importcsv"];
    string[] csvcolNames = (from dc in dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>() select dc.ColumnName).ToArray();
    string tablename = ddltable2.SelectedItem.Text;
    string[] dbcolNames = loadDataBaseColumns(tablename);
    int dbcol = dbcolNames.Length;
    int csvcol = csvcolNames.Length;

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //Find the DropDownList in the Row
        DropDownList ddlcsvcolumns = (e.Row.FindControl("ddlcsvcolumns") as DropDownList);
        ddlcsvcolumns.DataSource = csvcolNames;
        ddlcsvcolumns.DataBind();
        ddlcsvcolumns.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Please select"));

    }

        for (int i = 0; i < dgvmatchdata.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            DropDownList ddlselect = dgvmatchdata.Rows[i].FindControl("ddlcsvcolumns") as DropDownList;
            foreach (string col in csvcolNames)
            {
                string tablcol = ((Label)dgvmatchdata.Rows[i].FindControl("lblcolumns1")).Text;
                if (tablcol == col)
                {
                    ddlselect.SelectedItem.Text = col;
                    ddlselect.Enabled = false;
                    dgvmatchdata.Rows[i].Cells[1].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.SpringGreen;

                }

            }
      }
}
```

**Drop Down Selected Index Changed**

```
     protected void ddlcsvcolumns_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dgvmatchdata.Rows.Count; i++)
    {

        string selectcolumns = ((DropDownList)dgvmatchdata.Rows[i].FindControl("ddlcsvcolumns")).SelectedItem.Text;
        Label selectlabel = (dgvmatchdata.Rows[i].FindControl("lblColumns") as Label);
        TextBox txtcol = (TextBox)dgvmatchdata.Rows[i].FindControl("txtDynamicText" + i.ToString());


                if (selectcolumns.Equals("Please select"))
                {
                    selectlabel.Text = "";
                }
                else
                {
                    selectlabel.Text = selectcolumns;
                }
          }
```

}

Comment: Please post your GridView code here.